# why does KafkaMessageListenerContainer never relinquish thread from executor?

Tags: apache-kafka, executorservice, spring-kafka, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a program with multiple flows that access a shared resource. To avoid race conditions for the shared resource I've decided to serialise the flows with a shared single thread executor. I prefer this approach to plaguing the program with locks - my program will not be under a heavy load and it is not time critical.

One of the flows reads messages off Kafka, here's what the code looks like for that flow:

```
@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer kafkaFlow(DefaultConsumerFactory consumerFactory, ExecutorService myExecutor) {
    ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties("myTopic");
    ... //more properties
    containerProperties.setConsumerTaskExecutor(new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(myExecutor));
    return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory, containerProperties);
}

@Bean
public Executor myExecutor() {
    return Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
}
```

The problem is while the Kafka flow is working fine, the other flows never seem to get their chance at running. Why is that? I've used this approach with other JMS containers and they worked fine...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka requires the consumer to be polled regularly. otherwise it will revoke topic/partition assignments; the container uses a dedicated thread for each consumer.

You would need to `poll()` the consumer yourself rather than using a listener container if you wish to share the thread for other purposes, but you will still need to be sure to `poll()` within `max.poll.interval.ms` to avoid Kafka thinking your consumer is dead.

Comment: Thanks Gary, that makes sense. I can use the actual listener to submit tasks to the executor. What is a valid use case to override the KafkaMessageListenerContainer's consumer task executor (out of curiosity)?

Comment: 1. If you want to influence the thread names for logging purposes; 2. If you are running in an environment (e.g. Websphere) that doesn't allow applications to create arbitrary threads but must be obtained from a managed thread pool, e.g. with a `WorkManagerTaskExecutor`; 3 ...